# How could be the layered architecture / project structure? - Vaadin on top of Spring Boot Reactive with MongoDB reactive

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, vaadin, project-structure

Currently I have the following project structure:

**packages:**

- view
- controller
- service
- model
- repository
- config
- util

The view package contains the view classes of Vaadin.

Example case:
I would like to retrieve some data from mongoDB database after clicking a button.
The way to retrieve the data from MongoDB database could be MainView <-> Controller <-> Service <-> Repository, right?

Actually I am not sure how to structure my project. Could someone help me please?

Comment: We can not decide what architecture makes most sense for your project. Check the MV* patterns, try them in an isolated branch for one part of your application and decide _for your usecase_.  There are no silver bullets.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your best friend, see this blog/tutorial how to set this up: https://www.journaldev.com/18156/spring-boot-mongodb

Comment: I know how to use mongoDB. The problem is that I dont know how these layers are connected in my case... Thank you anyways.